# Saving multiplier JPEG images to PDF

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library

When I try to convert multiple JPEG images to PDF using PIL, "a.jpg" is saved twice so now there are three PDF pages containing two of a.jpg and one b.jpg. The following is my code. I want it to only contain one a.jpg and one b.jpg...

```
import random


def print_hi( name ):
    global random_int
    folder = "C:/Users/arjay/Documents/IntellijBackgrounds/"
    file_name = "a.jpg"
    img1 = Image.open( folder + file_name )
    img2 = Image.open( folder + "b.jpg" )

    random_pdf_name = "C:/Users/arjay/Documents/IntellijBackgrounds/"

    for _ in range( 5 ):
        random_integer = random.randint( 65, 90 )
        random_int = random.randint( 1, 1000 )
        # Keep appending random characters using chr(x)
        random_pdf_name += (chr( random_integer ))

    random_pdf_name += str( random_int ) + ".pdf"
    images = [ img1, img2 ]
    multiple_images = len( images )
    
    if (multiple_images > 1):
        img1.save( random_pdf_name, "pdf", reolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=images )
    else:
        img1.save( random_pdf_name, "pdf", reolution=100.0, save_all=True )

    print( "Successfully converted", file_name, "to", random_pdf_name )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi( 'PyCharm' )
```

Comment: You always append `images` to `img1`, and `images` always contains `img1`

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one image, your code appends the full list again - instead append from the second image onwards.

Change:

```
img1.save( random_pdf_name, "pdf", reolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=images )
```

To:

```
img1.save( random_pdf_name, "pdf", reolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:] )
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a ton!! Question, the images[1:] makes the list start at 1 and not 0, right?